# Android ListPreference Fill Item onPreferenceClick Event

Tags: android, listpreference

How to Fill ListPreference entry and entryvalues From onPreferenceClick event

I Filled From onPreferenceClick event But When First Clicked Getting Empty List 
When Second Clicked is Getting All Item.

Why When First Cliked Then Getting Empty List?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first idea that popped in my mind. Looks like a very dirty hack to get around, but anyway:

```
findPreference("yourPreferenceKey").setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

        private final String[] values = {"1","2","3","4"}; // Data set (as an example)

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(final Preference preference) {
            ((ListPreference)preference).setEntryValues(values); // Set new values
            ((ListPreference)preference).setEntries(values); // And new keys
            final OnPreferenceClickListener prefClickListener = this; // Store the reference to this click listener for a later use
            preference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(null); // And remove it from current preference, so it won't cause a recursion when we will emulate user click later
            YourPreferenceActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){ // Do some work after current listener finishes it's stuff
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ((ListPreference)preference).getDialog().dismiss(); // Dismiss the dialog that popped up because of our first click (with the old data)
                    YourPreferenceActivity.this.getPreferenceScreen().onItemClick(null, null, preference.getOrder(), 0); // Emulate user click. System will think that user clicked on the same preference again
                    preference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(prefClickListener); // Let's return our click listener back, so the whole operation will repeat on the next click (delete thi sline if you need preloading only once.
                }

            });
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: There is three ListPreference on Preference Screen.
my ListPreference is second.But Clicked Second ListPreference Opened First ListPreference. Why?

Comment: my ListPrefernce Position 3 But lpFiyat.getOrder() Getting position 2
why?

Comment: Try changing new Runnable to some specific implementation, where you will provide preference specifically. I can't really help on that stage, since I don't have a working code.

Answer (score 4):

When setOnPreferenceClickListener is called the dialog seems already created. A possible solution is to extend ListPreference and intercept the click on the view.

```
package com.example;

import android.preference.ListPreference;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class DynamicListPreference extends ListPreference {
    public interface DynamicListPreferenceOnClickListener {
        public void onClick(DynamicListPreference preference);
    }

    private DynamicListPreferenceOnClickListener mOnClicListner;

    public DynamicListPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onClick(){
        if (mOnClicListner != null)
            mOnClicListner.onClick(this);
        super.onClick();
    }

    public void setOnClickListner(DynamicListPreferenceOnClickListener l) {
        mOnClicListner = l;
    }

}
```

The new class have the public method **setOnClickListner**, you should use it instead of **setOnPreferenceClickListener**.

Then you can use *DynamicListPreference* in your xml preference file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <com.example.DynamicListPreference 
            android:key="id_list" 
            android:title="@string/opt_label" 
        />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

In your PreferenceActiviy:

```
package com.example;

import com.example.DynamicListPreference.DynamicListPreferenceOnClickListener;

import android.preference.ListPreference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyPreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        DynamicListPreference pref = (DynamicListPreference)findPreference("id_list");
        pref.setOnClickListner(onClickListener_mylist);
    }

    private DynamicListPreferenceOnClickListener onClickListener_mylist = new DynamicListPreferenceOnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DynamicListPreference preference) {
            ListPreference pref = (ListPreference) preference;
            pref.setEntryValues(new String[] {"1", "2"});
            pref.setEntries(new String[] {"first", "second"});
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Thanks - I think this one should be marked as correct solution - Alex Orlov's solution is very "hacky" and leads to issues if preferences are organized in categories.